# Debian laptop starts in grub command line

Tags: debian, boot, grub

First of all, I would like mention that I have very little experience with Linux, so please excuse me for bad terminology.

I have recently converted some school laptops from windows to Linux Debian in hope that they will run a bit better. (This is the first thing I have ever done with Linux)

They ran fine for a week or two, after which, most of them suddenly keep getting stuck in the grub command line menu.

I have googled a bit, and came across some things.
I had to point grub to the right place where `grub.cfg` is stored. I did this on all laptops, then told them to continue, and then updated the grub config file in the terminal

(steps I followed were listed on this site, among other places: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/)

Now when I start up one of these laptops again, they once again open in the grub command line mode. I checked the settings using the `set` command, and both the prefix and root pointed to the right places.

I can simply type in normal, and the laptop will continue booting Linux, without me having to change anything.

This makes me believe that all the settings are correct, yet it does not open the screen where you can select to start up Linux, instead getting stuck at the grub command line menu.

If I re-clone Linux onto the hard drive using the original master clone I used for all the laptops, it will work fine again, but I have the feeling it will get the same problem in a week or two, and I don't really plan on having to re-clone all the laptops every two weeks.

upon booting a Linux Debian laptop, it opens the GRUB command line menu. Typing `normal` will continue booting the system as normal, making me think the settings are all correct.

Is there still a problem with these laptops? Is there a way to make sure the command line menu does not appear?

Answer (score 0):

In you `/etc/default/grub` file, check to see if the entry `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` is set to `menu`, if not, set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` and also make sure `GRUB_TIMEOUT` is not 0 if you want to see the grub menu at boot. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` command after making changes.

Comment: There was no GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE line in the file, so I added it.
GRUB_TIMEOUT by default is set to 5. 
I updated it in the terminal.

It did not work, on reboot, it showed me the command line again.
I had to type in ´normal´ again before I could choose to boot linux
For clarification, I see something similar to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEL0D.jpg

Comment: What happens if you type `boot` at the command line

Comment: It says: error: you need to load the kernel first

Comment: There is entry in the `/etc/default/grub` file called `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, make sure it is commented out
Also there is sntery `GRUB_GFXMODE` set it to proper resolution of your monitor say for eg `GRUB_GFXMODE=1366x768`

Comment: GRUB_TERMINAL=console way already commented out. I changed the resolution to 1920x1080, which is the resolution of the laptop screen. Upon starting it up again, it still shows the command line screen

Comment: There's tool called `boot-repair`, try to install it and let it fix errors automatically and see what happens. Here's a link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I tried installing boot-repair via the terminal. When I add `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`, it tells me  E: dpkg was stopped. Manually enter `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to solve the problem. I proceed to do this, after which the laptop the laptop starts doing something and then freezes.

Comment: Try one command at time.  Firstly update your system using `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`, then add the ppa using command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair `, then again sync with remote repo using `sudo apt update` then run `sudo apt install boot-repair`. If it still doesn't work, you will have to download the `.deb` package of boot-repair and then install it manually using apt.

Comment: It gives the same error (dpkg was stopped) after both `sudo apt upgrade` and sudo apt install boot-repair`. I don't quite know how to install something on debian using apt

Comment: Can you install other programs (other than boot-repair) without any error? Try to install any small program say `htop` using command `sudo apt install htop` and see if it installs without error.

Comment: Also is it must for you to install debian? Try installing a beginner friendly lite distro say `Lubuntu`, it's a derivative of debian so there won't be much problem switching to it.

Comment: It seems I cannot install anything. As for using Debian or Lubuntu, I got given a laptop that had Debian installed on it already, and I cloned it to the rest. I can ask the guy who wanted to put linux on the laptops if that is an option. I will also ask him why I cannot install anything, maybe I am missing something that he knows about.

Comment: They have tried installing ubuntu and lubuntu, but it did not work as the install crashed when the bootloader was installed. Debian had a solution for this problem

Comment: You will have to dig deeper to find out what the problem and why is it crashing, try to do a fresh install of lubuntu yourself and notice any error messages and work on it. Also if `dpkg` is broken you can't do much with that distro then. Your will be very limited.